# Bootstrap dialog rendering postpode

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-dialog

I have come across a very bizarre behaviour of [Bootstrap Dialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)
For some reason, in the `foo` function provided below, the Dialog box does not show up at once. The rendering is delayed to the moment of reaching the line `$.get(...`. Any ideas why this could happen ?

```
function = foo()
{
   $rows.each(function (i, row) 
   {
       var $row = $(row);
       if (something_is_wrong()) 
       {
           alert_error('Something is wrong', $form, '');
           return;
       }
       // Some other code           
    });
    // The Bootstrap modal dialog shows up when reaching the point below !!!
    $.get('/sending_order_notification/' + legal_entity_own_id, function(response)
    {
        BootstrapDialog.show({ ...
        // ...
     });
}


function alert_error(message, $current_form, function_name)
{
    if ($current_form != undefined)
        $current_form.modal('hide');

    BootstrapDialog.show(
    {
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
        title: 'Ошибка',
        message: message,
        draggable: true,
        buttons: [{
            label: 'OK',
            action: function(dialogItself) {
                dialogItself.close();
                if (function_name != undefined)
                    $.post('/send_error_report/', function_name);
            }
        }]
    });  
}
```

**UPDATE**
Inspired by Maximus' anwser, I opted for the following work-around which worked for me. And yet this is not a clean solution, because I have to continue the loop even if it becomes senseless.

```
function = foo()
    {
       var bad_condition_flg = false;
       $rows.each(function (i, row) 
       {
           var $row = $(row);
           if (something_is_wrong()) 
           {
               bad_condition_flg = true;
           }
           // Some other code           
        });
        if (bad_condition_flg);
        {
           alert_errr(...);  
           return;
         }
     }
```

Comment: how do you know that it shows at that point? do you use debugger? is `alert_error` called?

Comment: Yes, I am using debugger. And !!! Most surprisingly - foo DOES NOT STOP when reaching `return` !!!

Comment: `title: 'Ошибка',` - russian language :)

Comment: Yes it is )) Are you Russian ?) I have across a thread when they say that JS always loops entire cycle `$.each`, and to stop it, one should use `return false` instead of `return`. But this does not work too. I think, the issue does not lie in BootstrapDialog. It lies in $.each cycle peculliarities

Comment: yes, almost) check my answer to see if it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the dialog to be shown, the browser has to perform repaint. Repaint is only possible when there's nothing in the call stack. So the dialog will be shown only after `foo` has finished executing. It's a bit different when you use debugger, because *sometimes* stopping at breakpoints gives a browser time for repaint and the dialog might be shown before the call stack is empty.

Comment: Well, then one solution is to have `var stop = false` before the loop, which turns to `true` if the bad condition holds, and then I check for the need to terminate after the loop, but it's king of stupid, because even if bad condition if met once, looping forward makes no sense. Isn't it possible to stop the loop in JS ?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan, I don't really understand the solution you're talking about... it's the solution to what? In the question you asked why the dialog is not shown immediately after `BootstrapDialog.show(` is called and I explained that.